# .htacces redirect subdomain to folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomaniain link "help.example.com", this is where i have build a functioning Wp site. I had a request from the client that he wants to reach this site by "help.example.com/something". The domain is on apache server.

I tryed whit he following lines in the .htacces file in the page directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://help.example.com/something$1 [P]
```

But unfortunately when I call the "http://help.example.com/something" URL in the browser the WP detect like a non existing subpage.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and suggest a solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you approach the issue from the wrong side. Have a try like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?something(.*)$ http://help.example.com$1 [L,QSA]
```

The other option is indeed using the apache proxy module as you already tried, but again you have to turn things around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?something(.*)$ http://help.example.com$1 [P]
```

The difference between the two is what URL the user will see once he successfully entered the page.

---

And a general hint: you should *always* prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do *not* have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Unfortunately this one game me an "500 Internal Server Error" error :S

Comment: the domain is on GoDaddy... the client chosed this hosting service, i think because it is cheap or don't know... and i dont have acces to the host configs unfortunately

Comment: I changed the `END` flag to an `L` flag, have another try now. This might be a problem if you are using a really old apache http server.

Comment: If things still throw an error then please take a look into the http servers error log file, that is where you can simply _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: now i don't get the error but the issue is the same as before the WP sees the "/something" part like a non exsisting page on the site... shoul I migrate all my files into a "something" folder?

Comment: No, why migrate? You should solve the issue at hand. No sense in turning away the moment something does not work right away. That is not how you solve an issue. As said above: take a look into your http servers error log file. You _cannot_ maintain a web page without that.